# string comparison for multiple values python

Tags: python, levenshtein-distance, fuzzywuzzy

I have sets of data. The first (A) is a list of equipment with sophisticated names. The second is a list of more broad equipment categories (B) - to which I have to group the first list into using string comparisons. I'm aware this won't be perfect.

For each entity in List A - I'd like to establish the levenshtein distance for each entity in List B. The record in List B with the highest score will be the group to which I'll assign that data point.

I'm very rusty in python - and am playing around with FuzzyWuzzy to get the distance between two string values. However - I can't quite figure out how to iterate through each list to produce what I need.

I presumed I'd just create a list for each data set and write a pretty basic loop for each - but like I said I'm a little rusty and not having any luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! If there is another package that will allow me to do this (not Fuzzy) - I'm glad to take suggestions.

Comment: Watch this, it will help a lot. Ned Batchelder - Loop like a native: while, for, iterators, generators https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EnSu9hHGq5o

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the [`process.extractOne`](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy#process) function is what you're looking for.  A simple use case is something like

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process
from collections import defaultdict

complicated_names = ['leather couch', 'left-handed screwdriver', 'tomato peeler']
generic_names = ['couch', 'screwdriver', 'peeler']

group = defaultdict(list)   

for name in complicated_names:
    group[process.extractOne(name, generic_names)[0]].append(name)
```

[`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) is a dictionary that has default values for all keys.

We loop over all the complicated names, use `fuzzywuzzy` to find the closest match, and then add the name to the `list` associated with that match.